# Use of substitutionGroup

Tags: xml, xsd

I am actually preparing for my XML exam, but I got pretty confused by the use of substitutionGroup in an exercise.

The point of the exercise is to give a valid xml document from a schema, so here is the schema :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:complexType name="A">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
   <xsd:extension base="xsd:integer">
    <xsd:attribute name="attr" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="B">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
   <xsd:restriction base="A">
    <xsd:attribute name="attr" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:element name="a" type="A"/>
 <xsd:element name="b" type="B"/>
 <xsd:element name="c" type="B" substitutionGroup="a"/>
 <xsd:element name="container">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element ref="a" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element ref="b" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

A valid xml documen for this schema is the next :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<container>
 <a>10</a>
 <b attr="hello">10</b>
</container>
```

Well I got pretty confused by this xml document and just can't get why it's a valid one since the choice only allow (a|c)+ or b+ element...
I know that the substitutionGroup="a" in the declaration of the element c is responsable of that because when I delete this statement the xml document becomes invalid.
I just can't understand why it's a valid document.

I hope someone will help me with this issue because it's actually driving me crazy!

Thanx all !

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `<xsd:element name="c" type="B" substitutionGroup="a"/>` means, among other things, that the element being declared (`c`) matches any content-model token which refers to `a`.  So in any valid element which has an `a` as a child, a valid `c` can be *substituted for* the `a`.  The group of all elements which can be substituted for `a` is the 'substitution group' of `a`, and `a` is the 'head' of that substitution group.

One way to think of is is that the presence of a substitution group for `a` means a reference to `a` in any content model is automatically replaced by a reference to "`a` or `c` or ..." with a choice group consisting of all the members of the substitution group headed by `a`.  (The spec even describes it normatively this way, although I think that would be a poor way to implement it.)

[Pause]

The trouble with the explanation just given is that although true, it does not actually address your puzzlement over the example you give.  How can a sequence of an `a` followed by a `b` be valid against a content model which wants either a sequence of `a` elements *or* a sequence of `b` elements, and not a mixture?

The answer is simple, and may reassure you:  it cannot be valid.  The example you give is not in fact valid.  Any schema-validator that says it is valid (including, for example, xmllint), is buggy.  Xerces-J issues the message

```
System ID: .../billel.xml
Main validation file: .../billel.xml
Schema: .../billel.xsd
Engine name: Xerces
Severity: error
Description: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found 
  starting with element 'b'. One of '{a}' is expected.
Start location: 4:3
End location: 4:4
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type
```

And Saxon says:

```
System ID: .../billel.xml
Main validation file: .../billel.xml
Schema: .../billel.xsd
Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.6.0.7
Severity: error
Description: In content of element <container>: The content model 
  does not allow element <b> to appear immediately after element <a>. 
  Expected <a> or nothing. 
Start location: 4:18
```

I expect your belief that the document was valid stems from using xmllint; unfortunately, libxml's support for XSD is incomplete, in part because the main developer found the XSD spec too obscure and too confusing to bear (this disappoints me but I can hardly blame him).

Comment: But since the element b is not being part of the substitutionGroup I do not understand why the xml document is valid. How can the element a and the element b can be at the same time present in the container since only one choice can be made between (a|c)+ or b+

Comment: Thank you for leading me to look more carefully at your example; I've added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Sir I would like to thank you for this answer, the schema-validator that I am currently using is in fact xmllint... I tought that my understanding of my XML lessons was wrong. I do not understand the choice of my teacher asking us to use xmllint, that kind of bug can be very confusing. How can it still be used as schema validator ?